# How to push new data input to top on the list

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

hello how to push new data to the top list using vue.js and laravel, I tried but still failed, I hope someone can help with the problem.

this is my Controller

```
public function addComment() 
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'comment' => 'required',
    ]);

    $comment = [
        'comment' => request()->comment,
        'article_id' => request()->article_id,
        'user_cid' => Auth::user()->user_cid,
    ];
    $comment = ArticleComment::create($comment);
    return new ArticleCommentResource($comment);
}
```

and this is my Vue.js Method

```
data() {
        return {
            data: [],
            comments:[],
            form: new Form({
                comment: '',
                article_id: this.articleid,
            })
        }
    },  
methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            this.showLoader = true
            this.form.post('add-comment')
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.article_id);
                    this.form.article_id = response.article_id;
                });

        },
 }
```

how to handle it, thank you

I hope someone can help

Comment: What you want to push and in which list ?

Comment: I want push my comment on the top

Comment: Without refresh the page

Comment: Do you mean at the beginning of the list?

Comment: you can use this.comments.unshift() to push to the top

Comment: @webprogrammer yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list simply loops through your comments array, you need to push the response at the first position of the list:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.showLoader = true
    this.form.post('add-comment')
        .then(response => {
            this.comments.unshift(response);
        });
},
```

This assumes that response is the actual comment (I can't see into your `form` class).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    import Form from 'form-backend-validation';

    export default {
        data:() => ({
            form: new Form({
                article_id: null,
            }),        
        }),

        mounted() {
          this.fetch();  
        },

        methods: {
            async fetch() {
                const response = await this.form.post('add-comment');
                this.form.article_id = response.comment.article_id; 
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please try this one.